# Sending query parameters using C#

Tags: c#, php

I want to send a string to a web API using GET. My string contains a few characters that are not accepted in URL or need to be escaped. How can I scape them and send them to the server?

If it helps, my server is written in PHP so any encoding needs to be reversed in PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by passing data to a PHP page from C#? It is certainly possible to use HTTP GET and POST methods from C# to hit any URL. The fact that a specific URL may be served up using PHP would be purely incidental at that point so I don't know that it is relevant to the question. If your Get URL contains querystring data with an "&: then it needs to be URL encoded. What have you tried? Please show the code you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data has HTTP Wildcards in it try to serialize or encode it that outputs a string doesn't contain any HTTP Wildcards.You can pass data with `uriencode` or some other encoding algorithm like for example (base64) :

```
 string byteArray = System.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourData);
 string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
 string exampleUri="a.com/b.php?data="+encoded;
```

Decode it in PHP like this :

```
 $data = base64_decode($_GET["data"]);
```

As i said you can also use uriencoding with :

```
 HttpUtility.UrlEncode / UrlDecode (You need System.Web assembly in your project)
```